# How to avoid warnings from subshells if the function in PROMPT_COMMAND is not defined?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm using the following code to get a nice prompt (including git information etc.):

```
function set_prompt {
    # magic happens in here ;)
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND='set_prompt'
```

However, sometimes I get the following warning after using certain programs that make heavy use of bash internally:

> bash: set_prompt: command not found

One good example for this is Gentoo's package manager `emerge` which shows that error when it exists. It's not a big deal - just looks ugly and doesn't break anything. But I'd like to get rid of it anyway.

I assume it happens because the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable is inherited by emerge's shells but the function isn't.

Is there some way to make the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable as not inheritable? Or another way to avoid this annoying issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't export `PROMPT_COMMAND` to the environment. The environment is for variables that are meaningful to all programs. But `PROMPT_COMMAND` is only useful in bash, so leave it as a shell variable. There's no point in having it be inherited by descendant instances of bash, either: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is only useful in interactive instances of bash, and they all read `.bashrc` anyway.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='set_prompt'
```